# Hibernate not see a mapping xml file

Tags: java, hibernate

im new in hibernate and try to write data in DB.
 my code

`hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory name="postsess">
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">123456</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgis</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">public</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
            <!-- Mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="net.sf.hibernate.examples.quickstart.Cat.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

`HibernateUtin`

```
package net.sf.hibernate.examples.quickstart;

 import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import net.sf.hibernate.*;
//import net.sf.hibernate.examples.quickstart.hibernate.cfg.xml;

public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Configuration problem: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}

public static final ThreadLocal session = new ThreadLocal();

public static Session currentSession() throws HibernateException {
    Session s = (Session) session.get();
    // Open a new Session, if this Thread has none yet
    if (s == null) {
        s = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.set(s);
    }
    return s;
}

public static void closeSession() throws HibernateException {
    Session s = (Session) session.get();
    session.set(null);
    if (s != null)
        s.close();
}
}
```

And get an exeption

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at net.sf.hibernate.examples.quickstart.hib_main.main(hib_main.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Configuration problem: Resource: net.sf.hibernate.examples.quickstart.Cat.hbm.xml not found
at net.sf.hibernate.examples.quickstart.HibernateUtil.<clinit>  (HibernateUtil.java:20)
... 1 more
 Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Resource: net.sf.hibernate.examples.quickstart.Cat.hbm.xml not found
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:444)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1313)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1285)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1267)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1234)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1162)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1148)
at net.sf.hibernate.examples.quickstart.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:18)
... 1 more
```

What im doing wrong. It a second try to execute simple example and again same exeption.

**UPDATE**

after changing path to mapping file in `hibernate.cfg.xml` i get another exeption in line `session.save(princess);`

```
 log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for  this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): net.sf.hibernate.examples.quickstart.Cat
at org.hibernate.id.Assigned.generate(Assigned.java:32)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:85)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:184)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:33)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:173)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:27)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:69)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:477)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:472)
at net.sf.hibernate.examples.quickstart.hib_main.main(hib_main.java:23)
```

`Cat.hbm.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 15.08.2012 12:46:22 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="net.sf.hibernate.examples.quickstart.Cat" table="CAT">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="cat_id" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="name" />
    </property>
    <property name="sex" type="char">
        <column name="sex" />
    </property>
    <property name="weight" type="float">
        <column name="weight" />
    </property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and main class.

```
package net.sf.hibernate.examples.quickstart;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

public class hib_main
{

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Session session = HibernateUtil.currentSession();

    Transaction tx= session.beginTransaction();

    Cat princess = new Cat();
    princess.setName("Princess");
    princess.setSex('F');
    princess.setWeight(7.4f);

    session.save(princess);
    tx.commit();

    HibernateUtil.closeSession();

}

}
```

Comment: Do you have `net.sf.hibernate.examples.quickstart.Cat.hbm.xml` there?

Comment: Yes. I add screenshot to question.

Comment: We need to see the class you call `save(princess)` and also Cat.hbm.xml. Best if asked as new question.

Comment: Im add this file to question please look at they.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to define your mapping resource in such way (using "/" instead of "."):

```
<mapping resource="net/sf/hibernate/examples/quickstart/Cat.hbm.xml"/>
```

I think this is a reason of your problem.

**UPDATE:**

About your second problem - I think that you forgot to define id generation strategy in the Cat.hbm.sql. For example:

```
<id name="id" column="CREDIT_CARD_ID" type="long">
    <generator class="native"></generator>
</id>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Hibernate uses it's own types. So in the declaration of id type yous should use not java.lang.String or java.lang.Integer, but simple string and integer. For example if you want to use string id you should define it as:

```
<id name="id" column="cat_id" type="integer">
    <generator class="native"/>
</id>
```

[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_mapping_types.htm) you can find the list of hibernate's mapping types.

Comment: Thank you its help but i get another exeption. Please see UPDATE.

Comment: Im add mapping file to the question. There are using `assigned` generator. Its correct? When i use native i get exeption `Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not get next sequence value`

Comment: It's correct. But this id generation strategy means that you will set id manually in application. If you don't want to set id manually, than change generator class property on "native". This will use DB default generator strategy.

Comment: So change to native it was right? What you can say about exeption in my previosly commentary? Another exeption from this error `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "public.hibernate_sequence" does not exist`

Comment: Yes. Change generator class to native. Especially for test purposes it will be ok.

Comment: About your last error - as I know you can't use standart generator strategies with String primary keys. I think better to change your id field type to int or long.

Comment: I have never used String as primary key thats why I can't give you advice how to implement id generation in case of String primary key.

Comment: Thank for answer i try this. Please read my question 5mins after, its helps if i get new errors)

Comment: I change type on cat_id to the Integer everywhere but get same exeption.

Comment: Thank you, you are wizard. :) . And i foggot to add `CREATE SEQUENCE hibernate_sequence START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;` to data base.

Answer (score 2):

You have two hibernate.cfg.xml.So remove one hibernate.cfg.xml.Try to test with below structure.And resource mapping is not trouble to you.You can declare only like this

```
       <mapping resource="Cat.hbm.xml"/>
```

[image]

Comment: It is a good practice to put mapping files near classes for which they define mapping. If you dont want always to put whole package name in the mapping declaration you can define package in <hibernate-mapping> element. + This will not cause his problem because only one config file will be loaded (from classpath).

Answer (score 1):

You should use `/` infront of path:

```
<mapping resource="/net/sf/hibernate/examples/quickstart/Cat.hbm.xml"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rename **Cat.hbm.xml** as **Cat_hbm_xml** as each '**.**' referring to a [sub package](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package#Package_naming_conventions).